# Model binding not working inside a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, partial

The problem I currently have is that in my partial view, the checkboxes are not being binded correctly by the MVC framework. The CaseViewModel.IsCaseSelected property will always be false regardless of whether or not the checkbox is selected. However, if I hardcode the html in the parent view instead of rendering a partial, then the CaseViewModel.IsCaseSelected property will be properly set corresponding to the checkboxes.

My code is shown below.

The form in my view looks something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div>
    <label for="ProfileName">Profile Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ProfileName"><br>
</div>

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_CasesSelection.cshtml", Model.Cases_Category1)

<div id="category2-cases">
    <p>category-2</p>
    <label for="select-all">Select all</label>
    <input id="select-all" type="checkbox" onclick="select_all_toggle(this)" />
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Cases_Category2.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.Label(Model.Cases_Category2[i].CasesNumber.ToString())
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Cases_Category2[i].IsCaseSelected)
    }
</div>

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
```

My partial view looks like this:

```
@model List<Models.CaseViewModel>

<div id="some-case">
    <p>some-case</p>
    <label for="select-all">Select all</label>
    <input id="select-all" type="checkbox" onclick="select_all_toggle(this)" />
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.Label(Model[i].CaseNumber.ToString())
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model[i].IsCaseSelected)
    }
</div>
```

The model it is binded to looks like this:

```
public class TestProfileVM
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$")]
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }

    public List<CaseViewModel> Cases_Category1 { get; set; }
    public List<CaseViewModel> Cases_Category2 { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, CaseViewModel looks like this:

```
public class CaseVM
{
    public string CaseType { get; set; }
    public int CaseNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsCaseSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Additional information:

Additionally, in my parent view, when I replace Model.Cases_Category2[i] with Model.Cases_Category2.ElementAt(i), the binding does not work correctly. What is the reason for this, and could it be related to the original problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess problem is the `name` of `checkbox` inside partial view. Hence you pass part of view model to partial page, name of checkbox will generated upon that model which you pass to partial page.

So compare generated name for checkbox inside parent view with the name of checkbox inside partial view and if they are not same, change name of checkbox inside partial page accroding to the name checkbox inside parent page.

Comment: Hello mo, the problem is indeed that the names of the checkboxes in my partial view do not match the names in the parent view. The reason for this is that my models are different. How can I modify my partial view to change the name of the checkbox, while keeping the binding? The new {name="name-here"} is overridden by the implementation of Html.CheckBoxFor().

Comment: Pass ViewModel to partial page instead of passing part of ViewModel to partial page.